# Scalerel package: to stretch, correctly, the `\benz` symbol

Tags: symbols, stackengine, scalerel

Starting from this question [Symbol for Fourier pair as per Brigham, "The Fast Fourier Transform"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576639/symbol-for-fourier-pair-as-per-brigham-the-fast-fourier-transform/576658#576658) and my humble answer with this code,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\benz}{\mathbin{\hstretch{3}{\scalebox{.4}{\begin{tikzpicture}
% create the node
\node[draw=black,minimum size=.7cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6] (a) {};
\node[draw=black,minimum size=.55cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6] (a) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}}}}
\begin{document}

$a\benz b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

is it possible (just only a my curiosity) to stretch, correctly, the `\benz` symbol using `scalerel` package?

Comment: I don't think this is a problem of `scalerel`, but rather of stretching itself. That's how affine transformations work. If you want an elongated hexagon, maybe you should draw it manually: `\draw (-60:1cm) -- (0:1cm) -- (60:1cm) -- ($(120:1cm)-(1,0)$) -- ($(180:1cm)-(1,0)$) -- ($(240:1cm)-(1,0)$) -- cycle;` or something like that.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio Hi, and thank you very much for your comment and suggestion. I am also very glady if you could put also your answer, thus I upvote you :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `scalerel` seems a little bit overkill for this task, tikZ has all you need. Furthermore, I think `scalerel` acts on the PDF-level (or at least DVI-level) and stretches the whole content as if it was a picture, hence breaking line width homogeneity along the symbol.

I'd like to propose a simpler version:

- using only tikZ
- with lengths defined using the `ex` unit which allows your symbol to stretch appropriately when your text size changes (though it will not work in sub/superscripts)
- a single double stroked hexagon
- stretching done by tikZ itself using the `xscale` option

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand{\benz}{\mathbin{\tikz{
\node[draw=black,
    double=white, 
    minimum size=.87ex, 
    regular polygon, 
    regular polygon sides=6, 
    xscale=3, 
    inner sep=0pt, 
    line width=.08ex] {};}}}

\begin{document}
$a\benz b$
\Large 
$a\benz b$ 
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

I just went to read the question you referred to and think the `signal` shape from `shapes.symbols` is better suited for what you want to achieve):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\newcommand{\benz}{\mathbin{\tikz{
\node[draw=black,
    double=white, 
    minimum size=.87ex, 
    signal,
    signal to=east and west,
    signal pointer angle=120,
    minimum width=2ex, 
    inner sep=0pt, 
    line width=.08ex] {};}}}

\begin{document}
$a\benz b$
\Large 
$a\benz b$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and...my sincere compliments for your explanation and your work. For me excellent and I have also known another information by your answer. For me is fantastic!!!! + 1 and check mark.